Infinite binary tree coloring
Problem
Suppose I have an infinite binary tree. Each edge of this tree is either blue or red (with probability $p$ it is red and $(1-p)$ it is blue). I want to find a probability that this tree has fully red layer, i.e., on the depth $i$ all of the edges are red.
My attempt
I wanted to use simple approach where I calculate probability of $A_i$ = ("layer $i$ is fully red and all previous layers are not fully red"):
$$\mathbb{P}(A_i) = p^{2^i} \prod^{i - 1}_{j = 1} \left(1 - p^{2^j} \right)$$
Then I wanted to say that probability that tree has fully red layer is
$$\sum^\infty_{i = 1} \mathbb{P}(A_i)$$
However this formula is giving incorrect results. For example, if $p=0.9$ the final probability is greater than 1.

This is correct and equivalent to $\displaystyle 1 - \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - p^{2^j} \right)$, but I don't remember if this product has an explicit formula.

@Adayah, thanks a lot. Could you give a hint how my formula could be transformed to yours?

Prove by induction that $$1- \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - p^{2^i} \right).$$ Or derive the formula from scratch by computing the chance that every level has a blue edge.
